# python script not working on cmd

Tags: python, windows, image, cmd, metadata

This is a simple code, its function is extracting the metadata of certain images. However, it would work on any linux machine via the terminal fine as expected, whether printing the metadata into the terminal or saving the result into a text file.

When it comes to CMD on windows which is the primary OS for my PC wouldn't work, even the shell IDLE for Python it doesn't create the file or even print out the metadata.

codes explanation, takes two parameters, name of image, and out << means whether it's supposed to output the data into the terminal or into a specified text file.

I can't actually spot where the problem is!!

Please help me to identify the issue !! Thanks

Here's the code:

```
from time import sleep
import argparse
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def getMetaData(imgname, out):
    """supported format of images are: .JPG, .TIF & .WAV"""
    try:
        metaData = {} # dictionary to hold the tags
        imgFile = Image.open(imgname) 
        print "Getting meta data..."
        info = imgFile._getexif()
        if info:
            print "Found Meta Data! "
            for (tag, value) in info.items():
                tagname = TAGS.get(tag, tag) # to human readable format
                metaData[tagname] = value
                if not out:
                    print tagname, value
            if out:
                print "outputting to file ..."
                with open(out, "w") as f:
                    for (tagname, value) in metaData.items():
                        f.write(str(tagname)+'\t'+str(value)+"\n")
    except:
        print "Failed!!"

def Main():
    print "Coded By: GentleMan"
    print "Created 2/24/2017"
    print "Use it carefully baby"
    print "Special for x6x.net"
    sleep(3)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("img", help="Name of an image File")
    parser.add_argument("--output","-o", help="dump data out to File.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.img:
        print getMetaData(args.img, args.output)
    else:
        print parser.usage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: sorry I didn't specify the exact problem. I don't get any error, because syntax is good. but it doesn't create the file, or show the metadata of the given image

Comment: can you please specify the command you are passing to terminal ?

Comment: ( extractMetaData.py img.jpg -o img1metadata.txt )         extractMetaData.py name of the script

Comment: is the image in same folder as the script?

Comment: yes, it's can you please run the script in your machine windows on IDLE or the CMD and see what  happens ?? you might have a deeper understanding of the problem, thanks

Comment: script is working fine for me, when i run it for random image and outputs None as well.

Comment: so where is the problem !!

Comment: I am afraid I cannot tell problem if there is none and works for me as well

Comment: This doesn't relate to your question, but it's just a suggestion. There is a convention in Python to name functions lowercase using underscores between the words. So your function getMetaData would be get_metadata or get_meta_data if following the convention. And the Main function would be main. CamelCase is used for classes.

Comment: well, I changed the name of the function, but still not working.

Comment: I just installed Pillow and your code appears to work.

Comment: Does it work on Windows!! if yes, what did you use and how did you do it!! anything will be appreciated